# PreserveSig for Non-Static Interop Method

Tags: c#, exception, com, interop

### Question

Can the PreserveSig attribute be applied to externally defined non-static functions? For example, can we mark the following method with PreserveSig = true:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.specialcells?view=excel-pia

### Research

Microsoft Docs outline the usage of the PreserveSig attribute for controlling whether an error type returned as a HRESULT gets returned as is or if it gets converted to an exception. But all the examples of this online apply to static methods e.g. see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.preservesig?view=netframework-4.8

Finally, if we are the one defining the COM Interop library then it looks like we can easily tell methods not to convert errors to exceptions by marking them with PreserveSig, e.g. see:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adam_nathan/2003/04/30/preservesig/

But the problem here is that it assumed we are the one writing the library. It doesn't apply to an external library defined in an imported DLL.

### Related

[.NET C#: Is it possible to import TLB (semi-)automatically and add PreserveSig to one type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994848/net-c-is-it-possible-to-import-tlb-semi-automatically-and-add-preservesig-t)

### Use Case

I am using the interop library Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to loop through each worksheet in a workbook and check for errors by using the Range.SpecialCells function on the UsedRange of each sheet. I access all the interop objects starting off with a click of a button on the ribbon, and pulling off the Application object:

```
Window window = e.Control.Context;
return window.Application;
```

I then use this Application object to get a workbook, and then the worksheets, and then the UsedRange of each worksheet, which is a Range object, part of the Interop library. From this Range object, I can call the SpecialCells function, but I have no control over the fact that it throws an exception to indicate no cells were found. I was looking for a way to tell the interop library "don't throw an exception for this method", or even a way of wrapping/overriding the method with a version that doesn't throw the exception.

Comment: The answer is on the linked Q+A is still valid.  But with the obvious pain-point that an Office interop library is rather large.  And subject to change outside of your control.  Meh.

Comment: @HansPassant I was unable to abstract the approach from the other answer and re-apply it for this case. I'll add more detail to the question to clarify what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, you cannot apply attributes to managed code that you don't control.